# making multiple sqlite3 calls in a shell script

Tags: database, scripting, shell, sqlite

i am looking to execute the following commands within a shell script:

```
$ sqlite3 /Users/riceje7/bin/places.sqlite
sqlite > .output places.txt;
sqlite > SELECT url FROM moz_places;
sqlite > .quit;
$ lpr /Users/riceje7/bin/places.txt
```

however the script stops after the initial sqlite3 command call and only executes the other commands after i manually quit sqlite. does anyone know how i can force the script to execute these commands in this order without having to manually enter them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing..

```
sqlite3 [OPTIONS] FILENAME [SQL]
```

so...

```
sqlite3 /Users/riceje7/bin/places.sqlite  "SELECT url FROM moz_places" > places.txt
lpr /Users/riceje7/bin/places.txt
```

Or better yet (unless you need to keep `places.txt` for some reason)...

```
sqlite3 /Users/riceje7/bin/places.sqlite  "SELECT url FROM moz_places" | lpr
```

Comment: lpr will be fine reading your data from stdin, so: sqlite3 /Users/riceje7/bin/places.sqlite  "SELECT url FROM moz_places" | lpr